# How many sets contains 6 or its multiple given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

[image: How many sets contain 6 or its multiple]

**MyApproach**

I created

@Edit

S1={1,2,3,4,5} ...B)

S2={2,3,4,5,6}

S3={3,4,5,6,7}

S4={4,5,6,7,8}

S5={5,6,7,8,9}

S6={6,7,8,9,10}

S7={7,8,9,10,11}  ....A)

S8={8,9,10,11,12}

From this information I analyzed that these $8$ sets have $6$ sets that have 6 or its multiple.

Thus $80$ sets will have $60$ elements which contain $6$ or its multiple.

Is my Ans right?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Wrong thinking process!!!when you say that in every 8 sets there should be 6 sets which satisfy the given conditions.. You are counting it wrong ...take two groups [s(1) to s(8)]{group 1} [s(9) to s(16)]{group 2} in group  1 there are two faulty sets that is (s(1),s(7)) but in second group there is only one faulty set that is s(13)...but according to you there are two faulty sets in this group 2 also...that's why you are getting an answer less than the right answer that is because of counting things which are not true..

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- The sets have $5$ consecutive elements so can at most contain $1$ multiple of $6$.
- For a multiple of $6$ find out of how many of these sets it will be an element.

Answer (score 1):

Note that  if  $x  \equiv 0$ mod$(6)$, the  $S_x$ contains a multiple of  $6$.

If  $x \equiv 2$ mod$(6)$, then  $x+4 \equiv 0 $ mod$(6)$, and so  $S_x$ contains a multiple of  $6$.

Similarly you can show that  $S_x$ contains a multiple of $6$, whenever  $x \equiv  3,4,5$ mod$(6)$.

It remains the case  $x \equiv 1$ mod$(6)$. Indeed,  if $x \equiv 1$ mod$(6)$, then  $x+1\equiv 2$ mod$(6)$, $x+2\equiv 3$ mod$(6)$ , $x+3\equiv 4$ mod$(6)$ , and  $x+4\equiv 5$ mod$(6)$  . Hence  $S_x$ doesnt contain any of the multiples of  $6$. 
Thus the number of $S_x$s having no multiple of $6$, is the number of  integers between  $1$ and  $80$  that have remainder one when divided by  $6$. These integers have the form  $6k+1$ with  $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now find  $K$, such tha  $6K+1 \leq  80 $, so  that  $K \leq  13.1$, so  $K=13$. Hence the number  of such sets is 14.  So  $80-14= 66$. $66$ is the answer.

Comment: @Freelancer what is $S_8$, isn't $\{ 8,9,10,11,12\}$, and  $12 $ isn't a multiplz od  $6 $ ????  By the way , how did you get the totla number od sets is  $76$ ??!!!  $S_x$ for  $x=1,2,3,.....80$, so we have  $80  $ sets  , rigt  ???!!!

Comment: OK!! Point taken it is nowhere written in question that every element of S(x) must be between 1,2..80 I messed it up !! Very much !! Sorry!! First I wrote s(8) instead of s(7) win my copy..and then which made a huge mess of my claim..

Comment: Now I see that  there are 80 sets ..and so as the sets s(1),s(7),s(13),s(19)...s(79) are ineligible that is (14 sets in all are ineligible or should not be included) and as total number of sets is 80 ...so answer is total -ineligible=80-14=66!! I misunderstood the question...which led to the huge mistake..sorry again..

Answer (score 0):

You can see that for x between 1 and 6 there are 5 sets which contains 6 or its multiple. and that will be the same for every x between y and y+5.

There are 80 sets so the answer should be  $\lceil 80-(\frac{80}{6}+1) \rceil$ = 66

Comment: Why I am wrong?I edited the code?

Comment: S8 should be {8,9,10,11,12} and I don't understand what you mean by "these 8 sets have 6 elements which are multiple of 8"

Comment: Oh I understand why you are wrong, Your way of analysing the problem is wrong. Sets that don't have any 6 or its multiple appears every 6 sets. You can't say that they are 2 every 8 because it's wrong if you take from S9 to S16 there is only 1 set without 6 or its multiple